# E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution). UBUNTU 20.04.3

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg, dependencies

Cannot upgrade anything since this error.

```
> milan@milan-ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update 
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Ign:3 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 InRelease      
Hit:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease              
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu focal InRelease    
Hit:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease            
Hit:7 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 Release        
Hit:9 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Hit:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease              
Hit:11 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable InRelease              
Hit:12 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
milan@milan-ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-10-base : Breaks: gcc-10-base:i386 (!= 10-20200411-0ubuntu1) but 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04 is installed
 gcc-10-base:i386 : Breaks: gcc-10-base (!= 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) but 10-20200411-0ubuntu1 is installed
 libatomic1 : Depends: gcc-10-base (= 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) but 10-20200411-0ubuntu1 is installed
 libc6 : Breaks: libc6:i386 (!= 2.31-0ubuntu9) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 is installed
 libc6:i386 : Breaks: libc6 (!= 2.31-0ubuntu9.2) but 2.31-0ubuntu9 is installed
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.2) but 2.31-0ubuntu9 is installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.2) but 2.31-0ubuntu9 is installed
 libcc1-0 : Depends: gcc-10-base (= 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) but 10-20200411-0ubuntu1 is installed
 libgcc-s1 : Breaks: libgcc-s1:i386 (!= 10-20200411-0ubuntu1) but 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04 is installed
 libgcc-s1:i386 : Breaks: libgcc-s1 (!= 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) but 10-20200411-0ubuntu1 is installed
 libgomp1 : Depends: gcc-10-base (= 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) but 10-20200411-0ubuntu1 is installed
 libitm1 : Depends: gcc-10-base (= 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) but 10-20200411-0ubuntu1 is installed
 liblsan0 : Depends: gcc-10-base (= 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) but 10-20200411-0ubuntu1 is installed
 libquadmath0 : Depends: gcc-10-base (= 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) but 10-20200411-0ubuntu1 is installed
 libstdc++6 : Depends: gcc-10-base (= 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) but 10-20200411-0ubuntu1 is installed
 libtsan0 : Depends: gcc-10-base (= 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) but 10-20200411-0ubuntu1 is installed
 libubsan1 : Depends: gcc-10-base (= 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) but 10-20200411-0ubuntu1 is installed
 libudev1 : Breaks: libudev1:i386 (!= 245.4-4ubuntu3.1) but 245.4-4ubuntu3.15 is installed
 libudev1:i386 : Breaks: libudev1 (!= 245.4-4ubuntu3.15) but 245.4-4ubuntu3.1 is installed
 lz4 : Depends: liblz4-1 (= 1.9.2-2ubuntu0.20.04.1) but 1.9.2-2 is installed
 systemd : Depends: libsystemd0 (= 245.4-4ubuntu3.15) but 245.4-4ubuntu3.1 is installed
 udev : Depends: libudev1 (= 245.4-4ubuntu3.15) but 245.4-4ubuntu3.1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I have tried a couple of things like `sudo apt --fix-broken install`
and some other commands from google but since I have no understanding of the commands I fail to resolve the issues Please Help !!!!

Comment: I would start by removing the backports ppa.

Comment: You appear to need `i386` packages, but do you really have a 32 bit system?

Comment: `apt-cache policy gcc-10-base` and also the simulation `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` please [edit] your question for that.

Comment: try to disable this http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu and run `sudo apt install -f && sudo apt update`